# cannot implicitly convert System.Type to object

Tags: c#, object, casting, system.type

I am trying to make the generic method for loading the form settings in .NET C# where each setting would contain it's own try catch block (to proceed with other settings when a single one is not valid). However I cannot figure out how to work around the assignment of the appsetting to an object. The comipler does not allow me to implicitly cast type of an object.

```
private void LoadFormSettings(object o)
{
  try
  {
    //Load settings when application is started
    Type t = o.GetType();

    // Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'System.Type'
    o = getAppSetting<o.GetType()>("Setting");
    // Cannot implicitly convert type 't' to 'object'
    o = getAppSetting<t>("Setting");
    // The type arguments for method... cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
    o = getAppSetting("Setting");
  }
  catch (Exception ee)
  {
  }
}

private T getAppSetting<T>(string key)
{
  string value = config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
  if (typeof(T) == typeof(Point))
  {
    string[] values = value.Split(',');
    return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't use instances of the `Type` class (value known at runtime) as generic parameters (need to be known at compile time). You could make your method generic instead.

Comment: Your exception handling pattern is not a good idea. 1) You're catching all exceptions, not just those you're expecting. 2) Avoid throwing those exceptions in the first place, for example by using `TryParse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type` is type and `t` is an instance. Generic requires type instead of instance. You can only write `F<Type>()` instead of `F<t>()`. In your case it's better write

```
Type t = o.GetType();
o = getAppSetting("Setting", t);

object getAppSetting(string key, Type t)
{
  string value = config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
  if (t == typeof(Point))
  {
    string[] values = value.Split(',');
    return Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
    public T GetAppSetting<T>(string value) where T : struct
    {
        string value = config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value;
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, default(T).GetType());
    }

var myBoolean = GetAppSetting<bool>("setting");
```